# "c-minus-minus" tag incorrectly named

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

I believe the tag [c-minus-minus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-minus-minus) should be "c--".

What appears to be the official website refers to it as "c--" (or sometimes "C–")

http://www.cminusminus.org/

Comment: I guess the reason is, "-" is interpreted as whitespace, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Andrew I think you're right. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c--` loads the tag wiki for [tag:c], although it tries to load questions tagged with [tag:c--] (there aren't any). IIRC there's a special case in the software to handle [tag:c++].

Comment: @Stijn no kidding there's no questions tagged c-- that's the whole point of this question is there's no c-- tag. Did I understand your point correctly?

Comment: @Celeritas the point I'm trying to make is that the software has issues with handling the tag you want to have.

Comment: @Stijn there *used* to be a special case, but it seems to have been updated now. See [Marc Gravell's blog post on technical debt](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2014/04/technical-debt-case-study-tags.html)

Comment: I would create the tag, [c--] and replace [c-minus-minus] with it. Anyone with 1500+ rep can do this, let the system destroy [c-minus-minus]. It's only six questions, shouldn't take someone with enough rep long, or if you really wanted to, make it a synonym.

Comment: @Joe we can't, when trying to add the tag it will automatically be replaced with [tag:c].

Comment: @Stijn I can't, I don't have enough rep to create tags. If you've tried to create the tag and you're unable (given you have enough rep), this is probably a bug.